# Porting ios apps to android

Tags: android, ios, porting

I write iOS apps and I want to start working on Android applications. I want to be able to port my iOS apps to android and have them look exactly the same. What kinds of resources can I use to port my app from iOS, objective-C code, to Android, Java code? If I can't get them to share one binary then are there similarities in the SDK to make the coding easier?

Comment: A similar question but in the other direction, comments and answers still apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535177/porting-android-to-ios

Comment: Create from scratch, and, never ever ever apply iOS UI Design in other platform specially android.

Comment: They are so fundamentally different that it is impractical to get them to look "exactly" the same.  In fact it is often undesirable.  There are really not that many tools that can help with such a complex task.  Your only choice, if you wrote your app in Objective-C, is pretty much to write it from scratch.  You can try a converter like this http://code.google.com/p/objc2j/ but I recommend against relying on an automated tool to produce an entire block of code for you.  You should know exactly what your code does.

Comment: You may want to consider stepping back and using PhoneGap, Cordova, Appcelerator (Titanium) in order to get mediocre-performance apps for both platforms.

Answer (score 11):

> I want to be able to port my iOS apps to android and have them look
>   exactly the same.

Don't do this; Android users *hate* it. If you don't care about Android, don't make the Android app. You're doing nobody any favors if the end result is yet another hasty port that looks exactly like an iOS app.

> What kinds of resources can I use to port my app from iOS, objective-C
>   code, to Android, Java code?

If you're looking to share code between the apps, you'll first have to port the iOS's business logic to C or C++ and then use the [ndk](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) as a starting point for the Android app. If that sounds like too much trouble, it's because it is (unless your app is a game).

In my experience, using a source code converter is a very reliable way to get buggy, slow, un-maintainable code. Don't punish yourself by pursuing this route.

If you really want to make an Android app, there are no shortcuts; you'll have to learn Java and the Android APIs. If you just don't have the time for that, hire a contractor. If you can't do any of these things, focus on improving your iOS app.

*UPDATE:*

While my opinions on this matter have not changed, the original caveat concerning games still stands. If you have written a game in Objective-C (rather than C/C++), [Apportable](http://www.apportable.com/) is an excellent tool for this situation.

Comment: So I just realized that a large portion of the mobile app market in Europe is for Android. I think that I'll try to make both types of code. I know enough Java to be able to go to the documentation and make an app, but from my competitive programming experience, *never* use Java. Slow and full of classes inside classes. Is there another option that has the same capabilities as Java i.e. animation and GUI powers?