# Converting iOs applications into Android

Tags: java, android, iphone, ios, objective-c

What is the most efficient way to convert iOs mobile application into Android? A friend and I are working on an app and we would like to know what is our options?

Can we translate line by line the code? What can we do?

Comment: See https://www.apportable.com/ to run Objective-C apps on both iOS and Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the codes by c language which are not related to UI, and call them by JNI on Android. If you did it, I think you can keep a same copy on IOS.

Comment: Like in Xamarin, the UI has to be done platform independent unless you want to run it in a webview on html5, etc... yuk.

Answer (score 1):

There is no conversion technique that you can just run your pre-existing IOS source code through and get Android source code

Unfortunately, that means you guys are going to have to decide if it is really worth the time and effort on porting.

Here are some resources for further reading:

http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/guide-for-porting-an-ios-app-to-android

[Porting ios apps to android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139612/porting-ios-apps-to-android)